# How to make virtual headphones in android/ios

Tags: android, ios, audio, headphones

I really have no idea where to start with this. I have android programming experience, but all my google searching are coming up as nothing. I am hoping someone in here can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to create an app that sends all sound (mainly media sound) on android devices (and eventually ios) over a network. I have a sound system that supports receiving sound, but their in app solution sucks and can only play local files. I want to fake headphones being plugged in so all sound get sent to this device. (It is a Pioneer AVR). Is this possible? What am I looking for? I cannot find it in the Android API.

Ideally it would be a user opens this app I want to create and "turn it on" and then your phone thinks headphones are plugged in or something similiar and then when they play spotify, youtube, soundcloud, pandora, or any output that it is sent to these "virtual headphones/speaker" and actually the sound is sent over the network to this pioneer device (VSX-1123K).

I would ideally like to create this with cordova or something, but if I have to build this native I will.

Comment: This might be possible by making a virtual bluetooth device. Is this possible on android/ios?